# How to count pandas datetime months by continuous season

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large time-series dataframe. The column has already been formatted as datetime. Such as

```
2017-10-06T00:00:00+00:00
2020-04-29 00:00:00+00:00
```

I want to plot the sample numbers for each season. Such as the following. The values are the count number of samples in that season.

```
1997 Winter 4
1997 Spring 8
1997 Summer 8
...
2020 Winter 32
```

I do make a little search and realize I can create a dictionary to convert the months into seasons. However, The most tricky part since the 'real wintertime' contains two years' data. For example, the 1997 winter actually should contain 1997 December 1998 January, and 1998 February.

Please note, I want the '1997 January, 1997 February' to be excluded from 1997 winter since they are '1996 winter'.

I am wondering what is the most efficient way to do that? It does not have to be named such as '1997 winter', any index should work for me as long as the counting numbers are successive from the beginning to the end.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a fast way to solve it, but it's not very orthodox...
You create a column 'season', and with a np.where(), you assign the season. At the beginning, you say winter for the first 3 month, spring, for the 3 next, and so. And then, you apply a shift(-1) on the column to shift it by one row back. Then, you've got your seasons (just ffill the las nan). You can then solve your problem in a lazy way.
If you're not confortable with the code, tell me, I will edit it.

EDIT:

I assume that the dates are in the index. If not, you should apply a dt.month instead of .month.
I decompose it to make it clear

```
_condtion_spring = (df.index.month>=4)&(df.index.month<=6)
_condition_summer = (df.index.month>7)&(df.index.month<=9)
_condition_automn = (df.index.month>=10)@(df.index.month<=12)
df['Season'] = np.where(_condition_winter,'Winter',np.where(_condtion_spring,'Spring',np.where(_condition_summer,'Summer',np.where(_condition_automn,'Automn',np.nan))))
df['Season'] = df['Season'].shift(-1).fillna(method='ffill')
```

EDIT 2:

Here a complete example :

```
dates = pd.date_range("1983-09-01","1985-12-31",freq="1M")
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100, 200,size=28)/100,index =dates,columns=["Sample"])
df = df.sort_index()
_condition_winter = (df.index.month>=1)&(df.index.month<=3)
_condtion_spring = (df.index.month>=4)&(df.index.month<=6)
_condition_summer = (df.index.month>=7)&(df.index.month<=9)
_condition_automn = (df.index.month>=10)@(df.index.month<=12)
df['Season'] = np.where(_condition_winter,'Winter',np.where(_condtion_spring,'Spring',np.where(_condition_summer,'Summer',np.where(_condition_automn,'Automn',np.nan))))
df['Season'] = df['Season']+'_'+df.index.strftime(date_format='%Y')
df['Season'] = df['Season'].shift(-1).fillna(method='ffill')
print('Sample for winter 1984 = ',df[df.Season=='Winter_1984'].Sample.sum())
```

EDIT 3:

Here the complete example if you have several rows for same month:

```
#### Build our df
#### This is just to make it clear that we will have 2 rows of each month. It could be more or less.
dates = pd.date_range("1983-09-01","1985-12-31",freq="1M")
dates2 = pd.date_range("1983-09-01","1985-12-31",freq="1M")
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100, 200,size=28)/100,index =dates,columns=["Sample"]).append(pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100, 200,size=28)/100,index =dates2,columns=["Sample"]))
df1 = df1.sort_index()
#### Now, to keep it clear, even if we could do faster, let's do a dataframe with 1 row per month with total of sample each time
df = pd.DataFrame()
df = df1.groupby(df1.index).sum()
#### Let's sort by date to be sure that it won't me messy
#### If you've got a 'Date' column and not the index, apply a .sort_values('Date') instead of sort_index
df = df.sort_index()
#### If youve got a 'Date' column, it will be df.Date.dt.month istead of df.index.month
_condition_winter = (df.index.month>=1)&(df.index.month<=3)
_condtion_spring = (df.index.month>=4)&(df.index.month<=6)
_condition_summer = (df.index.month>=7)&(df.index.month<=9)
_condition_automn = (df.index.month>=10)@(df.index.month<=12)
df['Season'] = np.where(_condition_winter,'Winter',np.where(_condtion_spring,'Spring',np.where(_condition_summer,'Summer',np.where(_condition_automn,'Automn',np.nan))))
df['Season'] = df['Season']+'_'+df.index.strftime(date_format='%Y')
df['Season'] = df['Season'].shift(-1).fillna(method='ffill')
print('Sample for winter 1984 = ',df[df.Season=='Winter_1984'].Sample.sum())
```

Comment: Yes, could you please provide the code? I believe it would be helpful for others as well!

Comment: Or I think there is another way, shift every sample 1 month later. Then I can group them based on the quarter. How do you think about that?

Comment: I've edited it. Tell me if it's what you thought about.

Comment: Hi, do I need to sort the DataFrame by the datetime before using that code? And what if there is no sample locate at a specific month, will it cause a problem?

Comment: You're right. It's better to sort by datetime before, if not, it will be messy. Sorry for not having thought about that. If there are some missing month, it will not be a problem, because, after having being sorted, the structure will not change.

Comment: Hi, I just think twice about this code. Since I am trying to count the samples in winter for example '1997 winter'. I think it should contain 1997 December 1998 January, and 1998 February. But it should not count samples in 1997 January and 1997 February. Will this code prevent it?

Comment: @Xudong, I'm not sure to understand your problem. I've edited a complete example. I assume that winter 1984 is from December 1983 to February 1984. Is it what you want? For example editing total of sample for winter 1984?

Comment: Hi, yes, that's what I want. I found a bug here. If I have 4 samples in 1983 December. Only the last one will be recognized as '1984 winter'. The other 3 samples will be recognized as '1983 autumn'.

Comment: Hi. I didn't know that you could have several rows for a same month. So, if it's the case, you should first apply a .sum() for each month before making the season column. If I find some times (today is hard for me), I'll try to edit the code to show how

Answer (score 1):

I think you should create a lambda function which selects the correct season by the value of the month and the day.

```
def seasons(date):
    m = date.month
    d = date.day
    season=None
    if (3==m and d>=21) or m==4 or m==5 or (m==6 and 20<=d):
        season = 'spring'
    elif (6==m and d>=21 ) or m==7 or m==8 or (m==9 and 20<=d):
        season = 'sommer'
    elif (9==m and d>=21 ) or m==10 or m==11 or (m==12 and 20<=d):
        season = 'autumn'
    elif (12==m and d>=21 ) or m==1 or m==2 or (m==3 and 20<=d):
        season = 'winter'
    return season

df['season'] = df.apply(lambda x: seasons(x['date']), axis=1)
```

Please observe that the seasons is also selected by the day. Because the wintertime is defined from December 21st to March 20th and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I found another work around method. So I would like to leave it here.

1. Shift 1 month later of all the samples
2. Attach seasons by the month
3. Then you can do with the samples in any way you want. For example

If you code it this could look like this:

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import *
    
df.loc[:, 'shift_time'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['real_datetime'] + relativedelta(months=+1), axis=1)
df.loc[:, 'season'] = df['shift_time'].dt.quarter
grouped = df.groupby([(df['shift_time'].dt.year), (df['season'])]).count()
```